# How to automate Android 6.0 Date picker to set any date?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

Can anyone help me on how to automate DatePicker in Android 6.0 using Appium and Java? I was able to automate it only for the current month dates. But I need to set the date for any date I am passing to the method.

[image: Date Picker image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally solved this. What I did was from the date picker I have taken the current year and the month. And from that I have calculated the number of taps to go forward or number of taps for go backward to the given date. Here is the code snippet for that.

```
public class Base {
    // Pass monthName param as "August"
    public int getMonthNumber(String monthName) throws ParseException {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").parse(monthName);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        return calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    }

    // Pass date param as "Sun, Jul 1"
    public String getMonthNameInThreeChars(String date) {
        return date.substring(5, 8);
    }
}


public class CommonLocators extends Base {

public void setAndroidDatePicker(String date) throws IOException, ParseException {
        int thisYear = Integer.valueOf(androidDriver.findElement(By.id("android:id/date_picker_header_year")).getAttribute("name"));
        String today = androidDriver.findElement(By.id("android:id/date_picker_header_date")).getAttribute("name");
        int thisMonth = getMonthNumber(getMonthNameInThreeChars(today));

        // Split the given date into date, month and year
        String[] splitdate = date.split("\\s+");

        int givenDay = Integer.valueOf(splitdate[0]);
        int givenMonth = getMonthNumber(splitdate[1]);
        int givenYear = Integer.valueOf(splitdate[2]);

        int forwardTaps = 0;
        int backwardTaps = 0;
        int yearFactor = 0;

            if (givenYear == thisYear)
            {
                if (givenMonth >= thisMonth)
                {
                    forwardTaps = givenMonth - thisMonth;
                } else {
                    backwardTaps = thisMonth - givenMonth;
                }
            }
                else if (givenYear > thisYear)
                {
                    yearFactor = (givenYear - thisYear) * 12;
                        if (givenMonth >= thisMonth)
                        {
                            forwardTaps = yearFactor + (givenMonth - thisMonth);
                        } else {
                            forwardTaps = yearFactor - (thisMonth - givenMonth);
                        }
                }
                    else {
                        yearFactor = (thisYear - givenYear) * 12;
                            if (givenMonth >= thisMonth)
                            {
                                backwardTaps = yearFactor - (givenMonth - thisMonth);
                            } else {
                                backwardTaps = yearFactor + (thisMonth - givenMonth);
                            }
                    }


        for (int i=1; i<=forwardTaps; i++) {
            androidDriver.findElement(By.id("android:id/next")).click();
        }

        for (int i=1; i<=backwardTaps; i++) {
            androidDriver.findElement(By.id("android:id/prev")).click();
        }

        String xpath = "//android.view.View[@text='day']";
        androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath.replace("day", String.valueOf(givenDay)))).click();
        //Tap on OK button of the date picker
        androidDriver.findElement(By.id("android:id/button1")).click();

    }
}


public class CommonStepDefinitions {

    @Test
    public void setDate(String date) throws IOException, ParseException {
        commonLocators.setAndroidDatePicker(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this solution is working. But If I want to select 5 years back date, then 5*12=60 times performing click() action on android:id/prev. Can we optimize this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @sandeepmaaram Thanks for the feedback. Yes we can optimize this. Can you explain the easiest way to select that day from this date picker? I mean the action sequence. Then we can optimize the code. BTW can you upvote this, since this will helpful for others?

Comment: Flow is like : Click on any button, picker will come > click on year > year list will come, scroll and select required year> then previous/next month selection> Finally select date.

Comment: @sandeepmaaram Yes you are correct. We can do it in that way.

Comment: can you please share information about the androidDriver you are using in your code?  Is it Appium?

Comment: @RameshNatesan yes as per the question, this driver is appium driver

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Android (Espresso only)`

```
$driver.execute_script('mobile:setDate', { year: 2020, monthOfYear: 1, dayOfMonth: 25, element: $driver.find_element(:id, 'android:id/datePicker') })
```